# while validating email id in android using kotlin always getting invalid email.I need to validate mails ending like @univ.ac.in

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

```
lass Mailvalidation : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var btnSubmit: Button
lateinit var edtMail: EditText
lateinit var email: String
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mailvalidation)
    btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit)
    edtMail = findViewById(R.id.edtMail)
    email = edtMail.text.toString()
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener {
        val emailPattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\\.)?(kanchiuniv.ac)\\.in\$"
        if (email.matches(emailPattern.toRegex())) {
            Toast.makeText(this@Mailvalidation, "valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this@Mailvalidation, "invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    }
}
```

\it should validate the email ending like kk@kanchiuniv.ac.in but its showing invalid even when the input matches the pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to escape the anchor `$`,  you have to escape the dot to match it literally.and you can omit the capture group around `(kanchiuniv.ac)`

You have 2 non capture groups which match the same and are both optional.

You can shorten the pattern using a quantifier `{0-2}`:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.){0,2}kanchiuniv\.ac\.in$
```

Or using `\w` for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

```
^[\w.+-]+@(?:[\w-]+\.){0,2}kanchiuniv\.ac\.in$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ikKuV/1) or see a [Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/Z3ppsX).

Example

```
val emailPattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.){0,2}kanchiuniv\\.ac\\.in$"
```

Comment: I have used the last pattern which u had given but still it shows invalid for kk@kanchiuniv.ac.in.help me please .actually I am getting input from edittext and checking it~  if (email.matches(emailPattern.toRegex()))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this@Mailvalidation,"valid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this@Mailvalidation,"invalid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

Comment: @KarthikKarthik The pattern works for the given email. What do you see when you log the exact content of variable `email` ? Is it exactly the same as the email address in the example?

Comment: I have no clue sir actually I don't know where it is wrong.Can u once check my code sir.

Comment: @KarthikKarthik can you run `print(email)` or `println(email)` right after `email = edtMail.text.toString()`  and see what the variable contains?

Comment: sir I am unable to find the value in logcat its showing a lot of other things

Comment: @KarthikKarthik Maybe you can print an easy to recognize string before printing the value of email.

Comment: sir its showing the value of email as "enter your mail address" which is the text hint which I had given in edittext..So how should I store the value which the user enters in edittext

Comment: @KarthikKarthik Perhaps the text is first bound, but you should get it again when listener is fired. So try getting the value `email = edtMail.text.toString()` right after the line `btnSubmit.setOnClickListener {`

Comment: I tried that but still same problem its showing kk@kanchiuniv.ac.in as invalid

Comment: @KarthikKarthik So now inside the `btnSubmit.setOnClickListener {` what do you get when you `print(edtMail.text.toString())` and print the value of the value of `email = edtMail.text.toString()` again like   `print(email)`? You have to make sure that you are checking the entered email address by the user. The demo code in the answer shows that the pattern works for that given email address.

Comment: @Thefourthbirdsir I am now getting the value which I have entered but still why its showing 
  invalid.btnSubmit.setOnClickListener {
            val email = edtMail.text.toString()
            println(email)
            if (email matches emailPattern.toRegex())
            {
                Toast.makeText(this@Mailvalidation,"valid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this@Mailvalidation,"invalid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

Comment: Pattern I used is val emailPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\\\.){0,2}kanchiuniv\\\\.ac\\\\.in\$"

Comment: @KarthikKarthik Can you verify with a hardcoded string that your code works with the email pattern from this demo https://ideone.com/Z3ppsX? `if ("kk@kanchiuniv.ac.in".matches(emailPattern.toRegex())) {`

Comment: I tried as hardcore string in if condition as u said still its showing invalid I have no clue of what to do sir help me please

Comment: @KarthikKarthik Did you try to run the example code from the [Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/Z3ppsX)?

Comment: sir can u send me your mail id

Comment: @KarthikKarthik You accepted the other answer, which had no rule for univ.ac.in

Comment: Check now sir please send me your mail id

Comment: @KarthikKarthik On SO you can reach out using comments instead. You can always create a new question and the community might help you solving the problem.

Comment: sir I have asked a new question regarding how to display multiple pdf files and their content in android app using kotlin can u help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern
...
val pattern:Pattern = Pattern.compile(
            "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
            "\\@" +
            "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
            "(" +
            "\\." +
            "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
            ")+"
            )

    fun String?.isValidEmail() : Boolean {
        if (this.isNullOrEmpty()) return false

        return pattern.matcher(this).matches()
    }
```

OR if you use android, you can simply use

```
 fun String?.isValidEmail() : Boolean {
    if (this.isNullOrEmpty()) return false

    return PatternsCompat.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(it).matches()
 }
```

Usage

```
println("aaa@zz.co.uk".isValidEmail()) // true
```

Comment: in android whatever pattern I use I am getting invalid mail only sir can u check my code once again and help me to fix please

Comment: @KarthikKarthik I have edited answer check it up